# ssrs How to Make very simple timeline using 3 date fields from same record using names as labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to show a project timeline in SSRS for a single project record containing a few milestone dates
Given the following data set: (Single record)
ProjectID   (Text) , 
StartDate   (Date), 
ApprovalDate(Date) , 
FinshDate   (Date)

I would like to create a chart ( Timeline) with each date, having the columnName as the label Like:
[image: simplest timeline]

Or Anything remotely like it..  It seems Simple,  I just can't get it..
I assume I would create multiple series?  And maybe use some sort of switch on the Name?  Having trouble getting it to work.  Even a suggestion on which type of chart to try.  I have been trying with a bar, line, and scatter.

Help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Check this link. https://www.advaiya.com/blog/how-to-create-timeline-chart-in-ssrs-report/  You probably have to turn columns into rows using UNION ALL in your query

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately I don't have sql access - only sharepoint list or service.